# Reformat input-output table in R

Tags: r, reformat

I have an input output table with the origin (input field) as rows and the destination (output field) as columns. Here's an example:

```
    Mexico  Thailand    Vietnam
USA 0   3   6
Italy   3   7   8
France  9   3   1
Germany 3   6   7
```

I want to convert the table so that the origin is in column1, destination is in column 2, and value is in column 3 so that it would look like this:

```
origin  destination value
USA Mexico  0
USA Thailand    3
USA Vietnam 6
Italy   Mexico  3
Italy   Thailand    7
Italy   Vietnam 8
France  Mexico  9
France  Thailand    3
France  Vietnam 1
Germany Mexico  3
Germany Thailand    6
Germany Vietnam 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple solution using the melt function from the reshape2 package:

```
#sample data
Mexico<-c(0, 3, 9,3)
Thailand <-c(3, 7, 3, 6)
Vietnam <-c(6, 8, 1, 7)
names<-c("USA", "Italy", "France", "Germany") 
df<-data.frame(names, Mexico, Thailand, Vietnam)

library(reshape2)
melt(df )
```

The package "tidyr" has a similar functionality.

```
library(tidyr)
gather(df, "names")
```